# How to pass parameters to the innermost function when i use python decorator with parameters?

Tags: python, decorator

here is my decorator for recall func when func return is not True

```
def deco_retry(retry_times):
    def _deco_retry(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while retry_times > 0:
                ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
                if ret:
                    return ret
                retry_times -= 1
        return wrapper
    return _deco_retry

@deco_retry(retry_times=1)
def func(ok=1):
    if ok == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

when i call func(), error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Charles/Code/pycharmprj/Huobi/test_code/decorator_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    func()
  File "E:/Charles/Code/pycharmprj/Huobi/test_code/decorator_test.py", line 10, in wrapper
    while retry_times > 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'retry_times' referenced before assignment
```

why can't i reference `retry_times` in the innermost function: wrapper, how can i correct this error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorators. This is the standard problem of Python creating a local variable for any name that is assigned to within a function.

Comment: thank you! I know the reason that I create a new local variable

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are re-assigning `retry_times` later in the function with `retry_times -= 1`, hence making it a local variable.

You can add `nonlocal` (if python3) right above the while loop:

```
def _deco_retry(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal retry_times
        while retry_times > 0:
```

Or instead of using a `while` loop, you can try looping with `range` instead:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(retry_times):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if ret:
            return ret
```

Should work the same, and you don't have to mess around with adding/subtracting the amount of retries.

Comment: Thank you very much, When I correct to the same as you, the problem was solved. and I know I am wrong because I created a new local variable.